# iOS best practices - Custom back action, popToViewController: vs manually removing the controller from navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Overview:**

I've 3 controllers A,B & C and pushing the view controllers as shown in the picture below.

[image: Navigation stack]

**Scenario**

I always want to pop the view controller to 'A' no matter what. Assume the below flow.

```
NC > A > B > C
```

There are two ways to handle the Back action.

• **popToViewController: -** pop to specific view controller, in this case 'A'.

• **Remove view controller 'B' from navigation stack**. In this way the view controller 'C' always pop back to view controller 'A'.

**Question:**

1. Since iOS back button (navigationBar.backButtonItem) doesn't have any action to be customized except pop, we have to add a custom left bar button as back button and add the button action to handle popViewController: manually.
2. In other scenario if we remove the view controller B from the navigation stack and leave the default navigation bar back button as it is. And when tapped on back button it will pop to view controller 'A'.

Which is the best option to proceed and kindly brief why is it better?

**Note**

View controller 'A' is not root view controller and not looking for code solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use `popToViewController:animated` API call to pop to desired viewController, you can use

```
if let viewControllerA = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as? ViewControllerA { //replace index 
   self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

to go back to 'ViewController-A' from 'ViewController-C' using custom leftbarButton and adding action to it.

From VC-B you can go normally using

`self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

**Edit:**

**• popToViewController: - pop to specific view controller:** this would be better approach as it uses UINavigationController API without overhead of removing any view controllers from the navigation stack, which will give clarity when reading the code plus extra advantage of going back to VC-B if some use case required in future to show VC-B so you can easily plug that in backAction of leftBarbuttonItem or call it from the code anywhere in VC-C.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've edited my question, 'A' is not root view controller. But the question is which is better option pop to specific vc or removing vc from stack. Also I need justification why the option is better from other.

Comment: edited my answers, removing viewcontroller from navigation hierarchy is little overhead since the API is available you can use it.

Comment: Agree, but I'm still looking for an answer why removing viewcontroller is bad practice.

Comment: both approaches needs some extra work, but using UINavigationController API is better I think cos you need to use loop to go through each viewcontroller and delete the VC just for going back.

Comment: @Tesqb3089 both are correct its on you which you want to use.

Comment: @suhit : upvoted, yeah I am having same thought on it. Still looking for a valid justification

Comment: @Tesan3089 edited the answer to clarify, you can upvote that if its feel right to you.